# jQuery 3d slide switch transition

Tags: jquery, css, 3d, slider, switch-statement

i want to create a simple content slider, that moves the elementes to different layers, take a look at the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ujmdjL00/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var offset = 0;
    var opacity = 1;
    var zindex = $("#slider li").length;
    
    var nextBtn = $("#next");
    var prevBtn = $("#prev");
    
    $("#slider li").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: -offset,
            bottom: offset,
            left: offset,
            right: offset,
            opacity: opacity,
            zIndex: zindex
        });
        
        offset = offset + 10;
        opacity = opacity - 0.2;
        zindex = zindex - 1;
    });
    
    nextBtn.click(function() {
    
    });
    
    prevBtn.click(function() {
    
    });
    
});
```

```css
#slider {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#slider li {
    background: #000;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="prev">prev</button>
<button id="next">next</button>

<ul id="slider">
    <li>Slide #1</li>
    <li>Slide #2</li>
    <li>Slide #3</li>
    <li>Slide #4</li>
</ul>
```

If the "next" button is clicked, the first slide should scale up and fade out, then the second should shown (every slide have to move, the first append at the end).

My question(s):

How to create such a loop?
Whats the best way - clone the first slide or move?

Should i use `transform: scale();` or manipulate width/height?

Also im not sure how to realize the animation - any helpful hints/links?

Thanks!

Comment: Having an array storing states would probably be a good place to start. It would certainly simplify figuring out which elements get which effects.

Comment: @bcdan thanks, my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ujmdjL00/5/ - but i have still no idea how to create the animation :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made it work like a circular carousal. I hope this should give you a good direction if not exactly what you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/ujmdjL00/12/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var offset = 0
        , index=0
        , totalCount = $("#slider li").length
    ;
    var opacity = 1;
    var zindex = $("#slider li").length;

    var nextBtn = $("#next");
    var prevBtn = $("#prev");

    $("#slider li").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: -offset,
            bottom: offset,
            left: offset,
            right: offset,
            opacity: opacity,
            zIndex: zindex
        });
        $(this).attr("data-num", zindex - 1);
        offset = offset + 10;
        opacity = opacity - 0.2;
        zindex = zindex - 1;
    });

    nextBtn.click(function() {
        var activeItem = $("#slider li.active")
            , index = parseInt(activeItem.attr("data-num"));

        UpdateSliderTiles(activeItem, index, true);

    });

    prevBtn.click(function() {
        var activeItem = $("#slider li.active")
            , index = parseInt(activeItem.attr("data-num"));

        UpdateSliderTiles(activeItem, index, false);
    });

    function UpdateSliderTiles(item, index, goingForward){

        var nextActiveItemIndex=0, dataNum = 0;
        if(goingForward){
            offset = 30;
            opacity = 0.4;
            zindex = 1;
            dataNum = 0;
            nextActiveItemIndex = 2;
        }
        else{
            offset = 0;
            opacity = 1;
            zindex = 4;
            dataNum = 3;
            nextActiveItemIndex = 0;
        }

        var NOffset = null
            , NOpacity = null
            , NZIndex = null
            , NDataNum = null
        ;

        $("#slider li").removeClass("active");

        $("#slider li").each(function() {

            var num = parseInt($(this).attr("data-num"));
            if(nextActiveItemIndex == num){
                $(this).addClass("active");
            }
            if((goingForward && num==index) || (!goingForward && num==nextActiveItemIndex)){
                $(this).css({
                    top: -offset,
                    bottom: offset,
                    left: offset,
                    right: offset,
                    opacity: opacity,
                    zIndex: zindex
                });

                $(this).attr("data-num", dataNum);
            }
            else{
                if(goingForward){
                    num = num+1;
                    NOffset = parseInt($(this).css("bottom"))-10;
                    NOpacity = parseFloat($(this).css("opacity"))+0.2;
                    NZIndex = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"))+1;
                }
                else{
                    num = num-1;
                    NOffset = parseInt($(this).css("bottom"))+10;
                    NOpacity = parseFloat($(this).css("opacity"))-0.2;
                    NZIndex = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"))-1;
                }

                $(this).css({
                        top: -NOffset,
                        bottom: NOffset,
                        left: NOffset,
                        right: NOffset,
                        opacity: NOpacity,
                        zIndex: NZIndex
                });

                $(this).attr("data-num", num);
            }



        });


    }

});
```